# Is there any simple Map Labeling Algorithm?

Tags: web-mapping, labeling, algorithm

I was looking into how to Label a few features on a small Map, and want to label them on the fly.

I would be adding a few features (a maximum of around 6 to 7) as graphics on a web-Map which has only a hypsometric rendered DEM. I would like to label these graphics and make sure that the labels do not overlap

I have looked at quite a few papers, but the algorithms look quite complicated. Is there any simple Map Labeling Algorithm that gives reasonable results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that there is a large number of papers on the subject should tell you that making a labeling algorithm that produces reasonable results is not simple. If you only have 7 text labels to put on the map and you're looking for a simple algorithm, simulated annealing should provide you with the best complexity vs. quality vs. speed ratio. The algorithm itself is quite simple, the magic is in the quality evaluation function.

Comment: I looked it up on wikipedia; It wasn't  as difficult as I Imagined that it would be.